How to use 2 inputs inside mat-form-field Angular Material with separately focus?
I have 2 inputs into one mat-form-field.

My issue is, when I click on second Input, the focus is automatically placed on the first input, I do not want to go to the first input.
Could you please help me to solve this problem?
html file is:
<div class="range-mat-input" [class]="field.gridCssClass">
    <label *ngIf="field.label">{{field.label}}</label>
    <div class="input-part">
      <mat-form-field class="double-input-field" [formGroup]="form">
        <div class="inputs-container">
          <span *ngIf="field.prefixLabelFrom">{{ field.prefixLabelFrom }}</span>
          <input appAutocompleteOff matInput
                 formControlName="{{ field.key + '_from' }}"
                 [id]="field.key + '_from'"
                 [readonly]="field.readonly"
                 type="{{ field.type }}"
                 [class]="field.inputClass"
                 [min]="field.min"
                 [max]="field.max">

          <span *ngIf="field.prefixLabelTo">{{ field.prefixLabelTo }}</span>
          <span *ngIf="field.suffixLabelFrom">{{ field.suffixLabelFrom }}</span>

          <input appAutocompleteOff matInput
                 formControlName="{{ field.key + '_to' }}"
                 [id]="field.key+ '_to'"
                 [readonly]="field.readonly"
                 type="{{field.type}}"
                 [class]="field.inputClass"
                 [min]="field.min"
                 [max]="field.max">

          <span *ngIf="field.suffixLabelTo">{{ field.suffixLabelTo }}</span>
        </div>


        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of field.validators;" ngProjectAs="mat-error">
          <mat-error *ngIf="form.get(field.key)?.hasError(validation.name)">{{validation.message}}</mat-error>
        </ng-container>

      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>

I try to make one mat-form-field with 2 inputs and separately focus. But the focus goes only to first input by clicking on second Input. I expect to solve this issue.

The Material Form Field is not designed to hold multiple form elements. You can create a custom component which holds both inputs, and control the focus state via FocusMonitor. See the following official demo from Angular Material as a reference: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples#form-field-custom-control

A mat-form-field is mean't for a single input field, So each input should have it's own form field.
Also you can use matTextPrefix and matSuffix to append text to the form field.
<div class="range-mat-input" [class]="field.gridCssClass">
  <label *ngIf="field.label">{{field.label}}</label>
  <div class="input-part" [formGroup]="form" style="display: flex">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-form-field class="double-input-field">
      <span *ngIf="field.prefixLabelFrom" matTextPrefix
        >{{ field.prefixLabelFrom }}</span
      >
      <input
        appAutocompleteOff
        matInput
        formControlName="{{ field.key + '_from' }}"
        [id]="field.key + '_from'"
        [readonly]="field.readonly"
        type="{{ field.type }}"
        [class]="field.inputClass"
        [min]="field.min"
        [max]="field.max"
      />
      <span *ngIf="field.prefixLabelTo" matSuffix
        >{{ field.prefixLabelTo }}</span
      >
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="double-input-field">
      <span *ngIf="field.suffixLabelFrom" matTextPrefix
        >{{ field.suffixLabelFrom }}</span
      >
      <input
        appAutocompleteOff
        matInput
        formControlName="{{ field.key + '_to' }}"
        [id]="field.key+ '_to'"
        [readonly]="field.readonly"
        type="{{field.type}}"
        [class]="field.inputClass"
        [min]="field.min"
        [max]="field.max"
      />
      <span *ngIf="field.suffixLabelTo" matSuffix
        >{{ field.suffixLabelTo }}</span
      >
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo
